# Rats like to eat cactus?

Tags: cactus

Rats like to eat cactus?
I have noticed that my cactus has become increasingly gnawed, and I have no idea what can be.

I'm starting to take care of gardens recently and do not know much about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rodents do eat Opuntia (also known as prickly pear) varieties - not necessarily rats, but other rodents too. You've not said what variety of cactus, but if it is one of the Opuntias, then likely the culprit is a rodent of some sort. Information can be found in this link: [Rodents That Eat Prickly Pear Cactus](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/rodents-eat-prickly-pear-cactus-60302.html) which refers to the States, so you may have your own local rodents which do the same thing.

Comment: I'm not sure the variety of the cactus, but I think it is a Cereus hexagonus. Thank your for the response!

Comment: I can't find any information on Cereus hexagonus and rodent damage - but if yours fruits, it may be they'd come for those...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, many animals including: Rodents, Rabbits, [Cows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIy64jnYaG8), [Deer](http://www.whitetailfood.com/whitetail-food-cacti/) and [Javelina](https://www.desertmuseum.org/kids/oz/long-fact-sheets/Javelina.php) eat cactus.